# Java Vector Why Only The First Element Is Being Showed In A Table

Tags: java, database, swing, vector, jtable

```
package ferramenta.database.transaction.command;

import ferramenta.database.transaction.*;
import ferramenta.database.transaction.dao.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * @author
 *
 */

public class RicercaProdotto implements Ricerca {

    private ProdottoDAO<Prodotto> prodotto = new ProdottoDAOImpl();
    private Vector<String>   myData  = new Vector<String>();
    protected Vector<String> vector1 = new Vector<String>();
    protected Vector<String> vector2 = new Vector<String>();

    @Override
    public void search(List<? extends Prodotto> lista, DefaultTableModel tableModel) {      
        for(Iterator<? extends Prodotto> it = lista.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            //Vector<String> myData    = new Vector<String>();
            Prodotto barcode = it.next();
            String valore = barcode.getBarcode();
            List<Prodotto> tmp = prodotto.selectProduct(valore);
            Prodotto p = tmp.get(0);
            System.out.println(myData.size());
            myData.add(p.getBarcode()); 
            myData.add(p.getModello());
            myData.add(p.getDescrizione()); 
            myData.add(Integer.toString(p.getQuantitativo())); 
            myData.add(Double.toString(p.getPrezzo()));
            System.out.println(myData.size());
            tableModel.addRow(myData);
        }
    }

}
```

In this way I get a table with the first row repeated

[don't work table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Piz8.jpg)

if I put `Vector<String> myData = new Vector<String>();` inside the for loop 
it works 
Where's the problem? I added 2 pictures

[works table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60fRp.jpg)

Comment: `if I put Vector myData = new Vector(); inside the for loop it works` - you already know the answer

Comment: Why if I put outside the for loop I got this situation? It's strange for me

Comment: If you create just one instance of `myData` and keep adding data to it, and then you add that same instance multiple times to `tableModel`, all your rows contain the same data.

Comment: Ok I fixed thank you